# JavaScript: What's global object and where does "this" refer to?

Tags: javascript

I've learned that in function invocation, `this` would refer to the global object. In the function below, which is the global object?

Is it the Function or there's a single default global object where `this` would refer to? In addition to that, what does this code actually do? I am particularly confused about the `method` placeholder. Does it have to be replaced with a method that's pre-existing in Function.prototype?

And in the line `this.prototype[name] = func;`, which property is it referring to, the method's or the Function.prototype's?

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` keyword refers to the current object, and if the scope of a function is the global namespace, the current object is the global object, i.e. the `window` object if the environment is a browser.

As you are adding a method to the `Function` class, the `this` keyword will refer to the function that you are calling the `method` method on, so it will return the function itself so that the calls can be chained.

This will declare the function `F` as a constructor, create an object of the type `F`, add the function `x` as a method to `F` and name it `xx`, then use the object `f` to call `xx` which really is `x`:

```
function F() {}
function x() { alert(1); }

var f = new (F);
F.method('xx', x);
f.xx();
```

So, this:

```
F.method('xx', x).method('yy', y);
```

is the same as:

```
F.prototype.xx = x;
F.prototype.yy = y;
```

Comment: so the "method" part in Function.prototype.method is actually a reserved keyword? Is that right? And the code as a whole just simply assigns a method x to xx?

Comment: @Joann: No, `method` is not a reserved keyword, it's just a name for a method. Yes, the code is just for adding methods to a class.