# What does "return this" do within a javascript function?

Tags: javascript

i wonder, what does "return this" do within a javascript function, what's its purpose?
supposing we have the following code:

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
  this.prototype[name] = func;
  return this;
};
```

What does "return this" do inside of a function?

I know what code above does, and what is the use of "this" keyword. I just don't know what "return this" does inside of a function.

Comment: @user722756: Because `method` is added to `Function.prototype`, `this` will refer to a function against which `method` was called. That function is presumably meant to be used as a "constructor", because `method` is extending the `prototype` object of the function.

Comment: i know the use of "this" keyword i just don't know what is the use of "return this" inside of a function .

Comment: `return this` is used to create a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). See the answers posted by @marcioAlmada and @AdamRackis below.

Comment: I guess you didn't understand my question.
I know what code above does, i just don't know what "return this" does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: What's global object and where does "this" refer to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758452/javascript-whats-global-object-and-where-does-this-refer-to)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

It refers to the object instance on which the method is currently being called. It's used for chaining. For example, you could do something like this:

```
myObject.foo().bar();
```

Since `foo` returns `this` (a reference to `myObject`), `bar` will be called on the object too. This is the same thing as doing

```
myObject.foo();
myObject.bar();
```

But requires less typing.

Here is a more complete example:

```
function AnimalSounds() {}

AnimalSounds.prototype.cow = function() {
    alert("moo");
    return this;
}

AnimalSounds.prototype.pig = function() {
    alert("oink");
    return this;
}

AnimalSounds.prototype.dog = function() {
    alert("woof");
    return this;
}

var sounds = new AnimalSounds();

sounds.cow();
sounds.pig();
sounds.dog();

sounds.cow().pig().dog();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jUfdr/

Comment: Why not illustrate using the actual code since extending the `prototype` is what it does? `AnimalSounds.method( 'cow', func... ).method( 'pig', func... ).method( 'dog', func... );`

Answer (score 14):

It means the method will return the object it belongs to. This can be useful if you want to chain instructions like so:

```
MyObject.method1().method2().method3();
```

Real world example: jQuery

```
$(this).addClass('myClass').hide();
```

Answer (score 11):

**tl;dr** returning `this` from a method is a common way to allow "chaining" of methods together.

---

`this` refers to the current context, and changes meaning depending on the manner in which you're invoking a function.

> With function invocation, `this` refers to the global object, even if the function is being invoked from a method, and the function belongs to the same class as the method invoking it.  Douglas  Crockford has described this as "mistake in the design of the language" [Crockford 28]
>
> With method invocation, `this` refers to the object on which the
>   method is being invoked.
>
> With apply invocation, `this` refers to whatever you set it to when calling apply.
>
> With constructor invocation, `this` refers to the object that is
>   created for you behind the scenes, which is returned when the
>   constructor exits (provided you don't misguidedly return your own object from a constructor).

In your example above, you're creating a new method called `method` that allows you to add functions dynamically, and returns `this`, thereby allowing chaining.

So you could do something like:

```
Car.method("vroom", function(){ alert("vroom"); })
   .method("errrk", function() { alert("errrk"); });
```

and so on.

Answer (score 2):

It returns this, usually meaning the html element that called it, but "this" can have various meanings
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html