# Javascript constructor function return this

Tags: javascript

I'm used to a javascript object constructors looking like this

```
function person(first, last) {
   this.firstName = first;
   this.lastName = last;
}

var dude = new person("the", "dude");
```

But sometimes I see the constructor return "this", like so

```
function person(first, last) {
   this.firstName = first;
   this.lastName = last;
   return this;
}
```

What's up with returning `this` at the end?

Comment: It's not necessary, the programmer didn't understand this.

Comment: Please go to the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300844/what-does-return-this-do-within-a-javascript-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no point in returning `this` from a constructor, but you are allowed to return any object you'd like. If no object is explicitly returned, `this` is implicitly returned.

A possible use case is:

```js
function person(first, last) {
  if(!(this instanceof person)) {
    return new person(first, last);
  }
  this.first = first;
  this.last = last;
}

var person1 = new person('first', 'person');
var person2 = person('second', 'person'); // <- without "new"

console.log(person1, person2);
```

Comment: Good example, I would still stay away from it :);  I posted about the ["forgetting to call `new`" problem](http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/08/constructors-without-using-new.html) for anyone that wants further explanation as to what's going on with this question.

Answer (score 0):

The only case that I know it could mean something is if you instantiate your objects in the following manner;

```
person.call(Object.create(person.prototype), 'Jack', 'Brown');
```

The above example requires that you return `this`;

What can be done, but should be avoided, is to return a different object than `this`

```
function person(first, last) {
    return {first: first, last: last};
}
(new Person() ) instanceof Person // false
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is returned so the caller can chain calls together.

`console.log(new person('First', 'Last').firstName);`