# Is there a way achieve method chaining with arrow functions?

Tags: javascript, this, arrow-functions

I was messing around with trying to chain methods and realized things weren't working in my example.

```js
var object = {
  method1: () => {
    console.log('method1');
  },
  method2: () => {
    console.log('method2');
  }
};

object.method1(); // works fine
object.method2(); // works fine

object.method1().method2(); // merp
```

I know arrow functions do not have its own `this` context so the situation that is happening above is the `window` context by default is being set and when the second method tries to trigger, it fails because it tries to find `method2` on the `window` object (please correct me if this is the wrong interpretation of what is happening) and [in order to achieve method chaining you have to `return this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300844/what-does-return-this-do-within-a-javascript-function) so naturally, this is a problem.

I know the simple solution is simple to use `function()` instead of arrow functions in the case above, but I was wondering if there was a way to achieve method chaining with arrow functions or is this simply not possible?

Related questions I've read: [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch)

Comment: In this case and only in this case, you can return `object` as it is already declared (to serve as `this`)

Comment: If you need to chain functions, you will have to return `this`. Also *I know arrow functions do not have a this*??? Arrow function binds parent context to the function.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir hmm interesting I actually didn't think of doing that. You should post that as an answer :P but yes it does seem that is a very specific answer to my scenario. I imagine there are reasons you would want to avoid that. Is the consensus then that if you want method chaining, you have to use `function()`?

Comment: @Rajesh English fail yeah sorry what I meant to say is I know arrow functions do have their own this context hence my explanation of how it was set to the window context Updated my question.

Comment: @aug In this case it works but not all object get stored in a variable first: `return { /* like for example this object */ };`

Comment: @aug The natural way that works for all cases is to return `this` and you can only do that using `function`s not arrow-`function`s.

Comment: you know you can still use function() {}.. it's still perfectly valid js.

Comment: @andygoestohollywood yeah I'm aware I was just curious if arrow functions had a way of intuitively handling this

Comment: I would appreciate a comment on why I got a downvote -- users don't improve their questions if you don't comment why.

Comment: only chance would be objects.call(method1).call(method1) to re-establish `this` context... otherwise, _not_ using an error function but the `function` keyword is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can pass the `object` as the first argument to `method1` which works nicely. But its not so nice.

```js
var object = {
  method1: (a: object) => {
    console.log('method1');
    return a;
  },
  method2: () => {
    console.log('method2');
  }
};


object.method1(object).method2(); // merp
```